# Event change Js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show to alert When a row of my table is modified but esta not work. Here my code . Thanks!

```js
      $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#table").change(function(){
        alert("The text has been changed.");
    });
});
```

```html
<table border="3" id='table' >
<thead>
<tr>Heading 1</tr>
<tr>Heading 2</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td contenteditable='true' id='bebe'>a</td>
<td contenteditable='true'>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td contenteditable='true'>a</td>
<td contenteditable='true'>a</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to specify in your question what is changing. Are rows being added/removed? Is the content of a `<td>` changing? A `<table>` doesn't know how to react to a change event.

Comment: From the jquery docs: This [change()] event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements.

Comment: DataTables plugin?

Comment: This will check for text change [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dff5mqkc/2/) and not with each keypress because it'd be a mess if the user is going to enter more than one character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED
This is when you want to check whenever the user pres a key in their keyboard

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    var val1;
    var val;
        $("#table tbody tr td").on('keypress',function(){
                val = $(this).text();
            //alert(val);
        });
        $("#table tbody tr td").keyup(function(){
            val1 = $(this).text();
            if(val1!=val){
                    alert("text has changed");
            }
        });
    });
```

This is if you want to trigger only when user leaves the box

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var val1;
var val;
    $("#table tbody tr td").on('focus',function(){
            val = $(this).text();
        //alert(val);
    });
    $("#table tbody tr td").focusout(function(){
        val1 = $(this).text();
        if(val1!=val){
                alert("text has changed");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! its works for me :D

Comment: Good to hear that :) Mark as correct and vote up then :)

Comment: The guy who voted down can explain why please ?

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted it.. but this answer is not complete, because it should be check for change in text too, also this way the alert will be fire with *every* keypress event, imagine if the user wants to type couple dozens of letters, the function will be executed with every keypress

Comment: the updated answer is fixed and it's fired only when are changes in text